# getting null row key after using primefaces filter

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

[image]When i am not using filter in primefaces datatable and try to select row then for example press edit it working well and takes the selected row.but when i use primefaces filter and then select the filtered row then edit 
i got org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled exception.

i know that mean i have a null row key but i don't know why.i am using a valid row key(id) the primary key of the datatable and when i use the debug i found that it get the id two times in the failure case,first time it got the right filtered id and the second time it get null id.
my question why it gets the rowkey id two times which get the null in the second time and cause the exception

```
    <h:body>
    <h:form prependId="false" id="growlForm">
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="false" />
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="dataForm">
    <p:panel id="ingerdientsTable">
    <f:facet name="header">
          <h:outputText value="Standard Food List" />
        </f:facet>  
         <p:dataTable id="ingedientsTable" widgetVar="ingedientsTable" var="ingerdients" resizableColumns="true"
                    selectionMode="single" selection="#{mealBean.selectedStandardIngerdients}"
                     rowKey="#{ingerdients.getId()}" value="#{mealBean.allIngerdients}" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,25,50" rows="20"
                     paginator="true" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px" tableStyle="table-layout: auto"
                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown} ">

                    <p:column headerText="Food Type"  filterBy="#{ingerdients.name}"><h:outputText value="#{ingerdients.name}" /></p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Protein(gm)"  filterBy="#{ingerdients.containedProtiens}"><h:outputText value="#{ingerdients.containedProtiens}" /></p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Carbs(gm)"  filterBy="#{ingerdients.containedCarbs}"><h:outputText value="#{ingerdients.containedCarbs}" /></p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Fats(gm)"  filterBy="#{ingerdients.containedFats}"><h:outputText value="#{ingerdients.containedFats}" /></p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Total Calories" filterBy="#{ingerdients.totalCalories}"><h:outputText value="#{ingerdients.totalCalories}" /></p:column>
                    <p:column styleClass="action-column">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Actions" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:commandButton id="addToMeal" value="Add To Meal" icon="ui-icon-create" update="addToMealDialog"
                            action="#{mealBean.showIngerdientsToMealDialog(ingerdients)}" immediate="true"
                            title="Add To meal" ajax="true">
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:tooltip for="addToMeal" value="Add To Meal"
                            showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" />
                            </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>
        </p:panel>




public class StandardIngerdients{
    @Id
    @Column(name="Id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FolderPathId",referencedColumnName="Id",nullable=true)
    private FolderPath folderPath;

    @Column(name="Name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="ContainedProteins")
    @NotNull
    private Double containedProtiens;
    @Column(name="ContainedCarbs")
    @NotNull
    private Double containedCarbs;
    @Column(name="ContainedFats")
    @NotNull
    private Double containedFats;
    @Column(name="TotalCalories")
    @NotNull
    private Double totalCalories;
    @Column(name="ImageName")
    private String imageName;
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer Id) {
        this.id = Id;
    }
    public FolderPath getFolderPath() {
        return folderPath;
    }
    public void setFolderPath(FolderPath folderPath) {
        this.folderPath = folderPath;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Double getContainedProtiens() {
        return containedProtiens;
    }
    public void setContainedProtiens(Double containedProtiens) {
        this.containedProtiens = containedProtiens;
    }
    public Double getContainedCarbs() {
        return containedCarbs;
    }
    public void setContainedCarbs(Double containedCarbs) {
        this.containedCarbs = containedCarbs;
    }
    public Double getContainedFats() {
        return containedFats;
    }
    public void setContainedFats(Double containedFats) {
        this.containedFats = containedFats;
    }
    public Double getTotalCalories() {
        return totalCalories;
    }
    public void setTotalCalories(Double totalCalories) {
        this.totalCalories = totalCalories;
    }
    public String getImageName() {
        return imageName;
    }
    public void setImageName(String imageName) {
        this.imageName = imageName;
    }


}
```

Comment: The error ypu get is not visible anywhere. Any stacktrace?

Comment: i uploaded an image for the error page i got

Comment: errors etc should be in text, not images. Searchengines cannot search in text in images. And did you debug the code where the error originates? And did you try the answer?

Comment: yes i do debug to the code and found that it entered the getId method of the row key 2 times when using filter one to get the right filtered value and the second get null  that's why i got the exception.i also tries the answer but i have the same error and i tried to move the datatable in blank page and i have the same error also.

Comment: My Question why it goes to the getId method of the rowkey two times after going to the edit method one get the right filtered value and the second time it get null?

Comment: Read my comment about the image. My new comment is please create a [mcve] so someone can try to reproduce

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem. The thing is I make my class to implement Serializable which guarantee the "integrity" (so to speak) of data in order not to disappear hehe... so your class would be like this:

```
 public class StandardIngerdients implements Serializable {
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code i think solve it

```
rowKey="#{ingerdients.id}"
```

Comment: Normally `#{ingerdients.id}` and `#{ingerdients.getId()}` are the same if you only need to have read access. It was a good suggestion, but since you state 'try' and 'think' you'd next time better post is as a comment first